# Umbraco how to use image property id to get URL

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

Ok am am very new to Umbraco/C# and what I am trying to do is loop through a custom media type to build banners for the home page of my application and the @bannerUrl always returns the images property id and not the file path to the resource. How would you go about retrieving the image file path from a custom media type created in Umbraco.

See code for example:

```
var mediaFolder = Umbraco.Media(mediaFolderId);
var banners = mediaFolder.Children();

foreach (var banner in banners)
    {
     var bannerUrl = banner.image;

      <div style="background-image:url(@bannerUrl);"></div>

 }
```

The variable `bannerUrl` always returns the image id by default and not the file path for the URL. How can I get the file path working? When inspecting the contents of the banner object in the debugger in VS I notice of the Url property has the following error:

```
Url = 'banner.Url' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

You would of though I could use something along the .Url lines but that dose not seem to work, so any suggestions how I would go about getting the URL the image property in Umbraco using the Dynamic way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solutioin if anyone happens to stumbles upon this:

```
 var bannerId = Umbraco.Media(banner.image); //banner.image is the property id.
 var bannerUrl = bannerId.Url;
```

Comment: Stumbled upon and used. Many thanks for straightforward solution.

Comment: You don't want to use this.  This accesses the database and does slow down page loading time.  Use the UmbracoHelper, specified below.

Answer (score 9):

To do the same within an MVC controller / API Contoller once you have the "media ID" you can also use the UmbracoHelper.

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var image = umbracoHelper.Media(mediaID);      // mediaID =  the (int)ID of the media
var imageURL = image.url;                      // imageURL now has the site root relative path of the media item
```

Answer (score 4):

It's much better to use strongly typed models in Umbraco nowadays:

```
var bannerMediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(banner.image); //banner.image is the property id.
var bannerUrl = bannerMediaItem.Url;
```